Disable Copilot Chat answering "typing animation" in VS Code
How to disable this annoying animation when one prompts Copilot in VS Code and Copilot is "thinking" for a while and then instead of just showing the answer it renders the answer letter by letter simulating human typing back.
How to turn that off? Because it is waste of time to look at this and slows everything down.
Also what is the official name of this animation for further googling?

Pretty sure it just be like that. LLMs generate tokens one at a time, and at the time of this writing, that "animation speed" is the speed that current LLMs tend to generate tokens at. It's not artificial slowness. It's actually that slow. Their work is quite computationally expensive.

Yeah - it streams in the response as it's being generated. Turning it off would make the response feel even slower.

Makes sense. Anyone knows if the LLM is really generating them in that speed or it is deliberate throttling of api to reduce potential spammers impact?
You know, something like saying to the consumers "hold your horses".
